# Magento 2 : specific product remove from quote

Tags: magento2, cart, quote

I set product's expire time in my custom module. When, product is expire at that time that specific product should be remove from quote. I used event **layout_load_before** for that.

Because, this code should be working from any page in whole site. If, any other event should i should then, please inform me that also.

### Actual Result :

Now, point is that if I remove specific product from quote. Then, product will be remove but minicart is not update.

### Expected Result :

When product remove from cart/quote then minicart also refresh and product should be remove from quote/cart.

How to do that ? Please help me.

My observer code :

```
$items = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllItems();
$createdAt = $this->_stdTimezone->date()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    if (strtotime($customModel->getExpireTime()) <= strtotime($createdAt)) {
        $this->_cart->removeItem($item->getId());
    }
}
$this->_cart->save();
```

Comment: What you're getting in $item->getId() ?

Comment: if you're getting the value then please try below code

Comment: $quoteItem = $quoteModel->load($quoteId);
 $quoteItem->delete();

Comment: I think you need to update section data as well.

Comment: Yes. Exactly @RamkishanSuthar . Actually, I know about I need to update section data. But, I don't know about how to update using observer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inject `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item` class in your construct as like below way :

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item
 */
protected $_itemModel;
/**
 * Add constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $itemModel
 */
public function __construct(
    .........
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $itemModel
    .........
) {
    .........
    $this->_itemModel = $itemModel;
    .........
}
```

Add this below code in your function

```
$items = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllItems();
$createdAt = $this->_stdTimezone->date()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    if (strtotime($customModel->getExpireTime()) <= strtotime($createdAt)) {
        $this->_itemModel->load($item->getItemId())->delete();
    }
}
$this->_cart->save();
```

**Remove generation/generated folder and clean cache.**

Comment: Thanks @Sukumar. It's working. Can you please tell me that layout_load_before is feasible event or not as per my requirement ? I checked many events but, this only single event is working.

Comment: If you want to check this on every page as minicart is loading on every page then its a correct event. Or you can also try this event controller_action_predispatch.

Comment: Okay :) Accepted your answer.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, how to check if item has specific sku, and delete only that from cart

Answer (score 3):

RamKrishna, is talk about the right point, you have to update the customer `Private content` after removing an item from the quote.

See [**the article for how  Magento  use update private data**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html)

As the private content is updated when **request type is  POST`**,So it means using layout_load_before on get Request you could changes Cart details OR user private data.

So, in this case, you have to perform **`a post request, which will remove the item from cart`** and have to implement `sections.xml` for update cart detail.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="{FrontendName}/{contollerName}/{POSTACtionName}">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

Comment: Correct @Amit Bera this is the right way to achieve this. Happy coding :)